# Is STAThread required for WCF service in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, silverlight, exception

I spent a really frustrated day to debug a Hello World Silverlight web application. The app communicates with a Hello World web service hosted on a remote Server via Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).

At first, the app constantly gave me the following error:

```
An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 
'http://remoteServer/service'. This could be due to attempting to 
access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy 
in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to 
contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and 
to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent.
```

After a while search on google, I thought that I came across the common cross domain problem. So I tried to add the cross-site policy file to the web root folder. But this did not kill the error.

Luckily, I accidentally saw codes of a WCF service online which has a "[STAThread]" keyword preceding the *main* function in the *program.cs* of the web service. So I did the same thing, i.e. added the [STAThread] before the main method. This simple trick magically cured the problem. But I have no idea about the mechanism behind this. Any one can explain it to me?

BTW: another issue is that when I host the service at localhost, the above error comes back, i.e. the silverlight app cannot communicates with the service. But a console application can communicate with the service successfully. I wonder if this is because the local host disables some system service required by the silverlight app in order to work with WCF while the server provides it.

Comment: How many threads or what type of threads a WCF service uses is completely independent of cross-domain access.  I see no reason why this "fixed" the problem, I think it's just a coincidence.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I have the same reasoning and thus get really baffled

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert here, but there are two types of "apartments" when your (managed) code interoperates with [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), namely **MTA** ("multi-threaded apartment") and **STA** ("single-threaded apartment"). If nothing is specified, when your application starts up, the thread of the `Main` method will have the MTA state. By specifying [STAThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.STAThreadAttribute.aspx) you force that thread to get the STA state.

If, later in your application, you create more threads, you can set their state using the enum [ApartmentState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.apartmentstate.aspx).

Now, I can't say what it is in your application that requires the STA state, and I don't even know if all WCF applications need to run in STA threads.